# Determine an action base on time condition

Tags: java, datetime, conditional-statements

Currently I'm working on a function that will do an action base on comparing values of local time and value of constant string/Datetime instance stored in a program.

e.g count++ if local time exceed a value String "3/25/16 15:00"(date/time) stored in a program.

How does one go about doing this? thanks

Comment: just compare dates and add your business logic

Comment: java.util.Date class has 2 methods you can use: before(Date) and after(Date). There are many threads here on how to convert a String to a Date.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
Date yourDateObject= formatter.parse("3/25/16 15:00");    
Date dateobj = new Date(); //current date

if(dateobj.after(yourDateObject)){
    count++;
}
```